# SQL statement in MS Access with parameters of type date

Tags: c#, ms-access, port

I have a SQL statement for querying in MS Access. I want to get the result of the transaction between dates.

This is my code:

```
 DateTime pFromNew = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
 DateTime pToNew = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

 string pFrom = "#" + pFromNew.ToString() + "#";
 string pTo = "#" + pToNew.ToString() + "#";

 chrTrans.Series["Class"].Points.Clear();

 oconn.Open();

 OleDbCommand cmd = oconn.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

 cmd.CommandText = "Select ClassType,Nametree,TransWeight,Valuedate  from tblTrans where Nametree = '" + this.cboNametree.Text.Trim() + "' and valuedate between '" + pFrom + "' and '" + pTo + "'";
 //+ "' and valuedate between '"+ this.dateTimePicker1.Text +"' and '"+ this.dateTimePicker2.Text +"'";

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What is wrong with this statement?

I always get this error:

> DATA Type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but I thought you didn't need `'` around the date. Instead of `'#1/1/2018#'` you would do `#1/1/2018#`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes you have in your string... I will show you...

This line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select ClassType,Nametree,TransWeight,Valuedate  from tblTrans where Nametree = '" + this.cboNametree.Text.Trim() + "' and valuedate between '" + pFrom + "' and '" + pTo + "'";
```

Should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select ClassType,Nametree,TransWeight,Valuedate  from tblTrans where Nametree = '" + this.cboNametree.Text.Trim() + "' and valuedate between " + pFrom + " and " + pTo;
```

The reason is that you already concatenated a # symbol around your date strings--and the single quote thus is not needed.

Comment: If that helped please mark as answer by clicking the green check mark to the left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this too complicated, converting back and forth three times.

It can be reduced to:

```
string pFrom = "#" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
string pTo = "#" + this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";

// snip

cmd.CommandText = "Select ClassType,Nametree,TransWeight,Valuedate from tblTrans where Nametree = '" + this.cboNametree.Text.Trim() + "' and valuedate between " + pFrom + " and " + pTo + "";
```